# Scaling and Performance

Tags: opengl, graphics, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

I've never been able to understand the best practice in this context . I usually want to ship my game with as minimum size as possible. so where ever possible , I try to use scaling of graphics . Let us suppose I have to draw a 1000 X 300 px wall of yellow color in my game. So I usually just use a 3 X 3 px yellow image and stretch it in game (using nearest neighbor filter). Is this the right approach ?

Let us consider another situation . Let us suppose I wish to render rain in my game . Basically 2 X 30 px blue white gradient streaks . Let us suppose at any time 200 drops max are going to be rendered . Now if I just ship a 2 X 6 px streak with the game and scale it at runtime , will it affect performance .

In short how does scaling affect performance in OpenGL?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about how texture size affects OpenGL performance? Did you tested it yourself on your game, what results did you get?

Comment: Why do you even use a texture for a gradient (assuming it's a simple two color one)?

Comment: I use Textures for gradient because I use batching (libgdx sprite batch) and have a feeling that too many hops between primitive shape rendering and texture rendering will degrade performance (I have to end the batch before beginning rendering primitive shapes)

Comment: @KromStern I am not talking about texture size affecting performance , instead I wish to know how stretching too often and too much affects performance

Comment: Maybe if you rephrase your question it will make more sense. At the moment it's hard to figure it out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the same is active on gamedev.stackexchange  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81856/does-scaling-affect-performance-in-opengl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are asking if scaling the textures will affect rendering performance?

For your wall example in the vertex shader there will be no difference. In the fragment shader you will sample the texture and the GPU will simply multiply the texture coordinate by the size of the texture and then round the resulting coordinates and grab the corresponding pixel from the texture buffer. It doesn't matter how large the texture is the operations are the same.

Same issue with the rain besides that linear scaling will grab some more pixels and combine them according to how close the texture coordinate is to them.

Besides these issues you should think of the memory requirements of storing the textures in the GPU 9 pixels needs a lot less memory than 300,000 pixels.

Comment: This is what I had assumed but this guy seems to say something strange then : http://goo.gl/m4IVfZ

Comment: Note that he doesn't say whether he actually tested his assumption but just went ahead with it

Comment: The number of operations may be the same, but sampling from a smaller texture will generally give you better cache hit rates because the memory accesses are more local. Cache misses are expensive, so this can make a very substantial difference.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a little advice. If your target is to minimize app weight, I would recommend you generate one-pixel size white Texture and use it with different colors for every case where possible (e.g. wall of monochrome green color).

```
public static Texture createPixelTexture() {
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.drawPixel(0, 0, Color.WHITE.toIntBits());
        Texture texture = new Texture(pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
        return texture;
    }
```

Be aware of this method gives you [unmanaged texture](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1073). It means that you have to recreate it each time your app loses context and of course you have to call dipsose for it.

This is suitable when you just need to draw something monochrome, if you need in gradient approach you get another problem... And in this situation you may use same one-pixel white texture with your custom fragment shader. But this way is a way of serious guys who love to get in troubles and then solve them (sometimes very slowly), because managing of different shaders (I'm sure you need 2 at least) will complicate your drawing cycle, and you have to manage them somehow...

So, I just wanted give you a point. Good luck!